# как сделать так ,чтоб текст не залазил на картинку

Tags: html, css

как сделать так ,чтоб текст не залазил на картинку ( отмечен голубым ) ,у картинки создан position absolute,но его убрать нельзя,ибо уйдет другой текст.Надо чтоб как то этот текст был внизу страницы,как новый отдел можно сказать,чтоб задать еще одну картинку на фон

[image: ы]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    /* margin-left: 350px; */
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background:  rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.logo {
    padding: 0.9em;
    color: peachpuff;
}

.navlist {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
.navlist a {
    display: block;
    color: peachpuff;
    padding: 1.5em;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.navlist a:hover {
    transition: 0.8s;
    color: rgb(206, 197, 197);
    font-size: 17px;
}
  
  .navlist a span
  {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .navlist a span::before
  {
    transition: width .9s;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: currentColor;
  }
  
  .navlist a:hover span::before
  {
    width: 100%;
  }

.num {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 730px;
    padding: 1.5em;
    color: peachpuff;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.contacts a {
  color: peachpuff;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.contacts {
    display: flex;
    transition: 0.8s;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-left: 210px;
}

.instcont {
  transition: 0.8s;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.vkcont, .whatsappcont {
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.vkcont a:hover {
  font-size: 27px;
  transition: 0.8s;
  color: rgb(206, 197, 197);
}

.instcont a:hover {
  font-size: 27px;
  transition: 0.8s;
  color: rgb(206, 197, 197);
}

.whatsappcont a:hover {
  transition: 0.8s;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: rgb(206, 197, 197);
}

.coverinmg {
  position: ;
}

.coverimg img {
  position: absolute;
    /* width: 1920px;
    height: 965px; */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
}

.headtextcover {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.maindesigncont, .buttonform {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.maindesigncont {
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.designcurtaincover {
  background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.205);
  background-size: 100px 20px;
  padding: 2em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgb(252, 210, 173);
}

.buttonform1 {
  border: 1px solid rgba(252, 252, 250, 0);
  background-color: burlywood;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: 0.8s;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.buttonform1 a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.buttonform1:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 0.8s;
  color: peachpuff;
  transition: 0.8s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonform1:hover .tchildbuttonform a {
  color: peachpuff;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/css/mainpage.css">
    <link href="/static/styles/fontawesome/fontawesomecss/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/styles/fontawesome/fontawesomecss/brands.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/styles/fontawesome/fontawesomecss/solid.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
     <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
          <h1>CURTAINS</h1>
        </div>

         <ul class="navlist" >
            <li><a href=""><span>О нас</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Услуги</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Материалы</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Наши работы</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Отзывы</span></a></li>
          </ul>

            <div class="num">
              <span>+8 987 626 99 70</span>
            </div>

          <div class="socmedia">
            <div class="contacts">
                     <div class="instcont">
                       <a href="">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                       </a>
                     </div>
                    <div class="vkcont">
                      <a href="">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-vk"></i>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                     <div class="whatsappcont">
                       <a href="">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
                       </a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
  <div class="cover">
    <div class="coverimg">
      <img src="static/images/sinitta-leunen-38agrOgtKT0-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="maindesigncont">
      <div class="designcurtaincover">
          <p class="headtextcover">Дизайнер по шторам</p>
          <br>
          <p>Дизайн штор - это не только прекрасное украшение интерьера, 
            <br>но и способ создания атмосферы уюта и комфорта в доме.<br> 
            Важно учитывать не только эстетику, но и функциональность <br>
            штор - они должны защищать от солнца, шума и посторонних глаз.</p>
            <br>
          <p>Для оформления окон можно использовать карнизы, аксессуары для штор, 
            <br>а так же их разные виды: открытые шторы, рулонные шторы и др.<br>
             Каждый тип штор имеет свои особенности и преимущества, и 
             <br>правильный выбор поможет добиться желаемого результата.</p>
             <br>
          <p>Наша компания предлагает высококачественные шторы и 
            <br>уникальные дизайнерские решения для каждого клиента.<br>
             Мы поможем подобрать идеальный вариант для вашего дома или офиса,
             <br> установим карнизы и произведем установку штор.</p>
             <br>
          <p>Кроме того, наша компания гарантирует доступные 
            <br> цены и скидки на все виды штор. <br>
            Мы работаем только с качественными материалами и
            <br> обеспечиваем гарантию на все продукты.</p>
            <br>
          <p>Нужно купить шторы? Воспользуйтесь нашими услугами <br>
            и получите красивые, функциональные шторы по выгодной цене!<br>
             Наши специалисты всегда готовы помочь вам подобрать идеальные шторы <br>
             в соответствии со стилем и функциональностью помещения.</p>
        
          
         <br>
        <div class="buttonform">
          <div class="childbuttonform">
              <form action="https://youtube" target="_blank">
                 <button class="buttonform1"><span>Оставить заявку</span></button>
              </form>
              </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="secondpage">
    <div class="sptext">
      <span>Что нужно учитывать при выборе ткани</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так у Вас же этот текст не залазит на картинку... Он у Вас под картинкой...Или Вы что-то другое имели ввиду? [![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qzc9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qzc9.png)

Comment: не-а,он у меня на картинке.Надо чтоб был прям под картинкой ( белый фон чтоб был )

Comment: именно здесь эта надпись находится внизу под картинкой. Не понимаю в чем проблема

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй картинку вставить  через css для класса `.maindesigncont` пропиши `background: url(Путь к картинке) center/100% no-repeat;` а из html удали полностью ее